# Can this be victim of sql injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-injection

Hi I am getting id value from a drop down list and passing it to a code behind method which passes value to sql to do some operation.

I was wondering if it is the right way of doing it.

if it is not then why not and how someone can inject it with sql injection and what would be the solution.

```
   protected void Drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
               int abcID;
                    abcID= Convert.ToInt32(drop1.SelectedItem.Value);

    string sc = "SELECT dddd FROM table1 WHERE abcID NOT IN("
                    +  abcID + ")";

                using (SqlDataSource ds = new SqlDataSource(ConnectionString(), sc ))
                {
    }
```

Comment: Its just not a good practice I think.

Comment: if the input is `1,2) or (1=1`

Comment: `1);DROP TABLE Table1 --`

Comment: it's a drop down list populated from database, so there is no chance of user entering any values unless they use something I am not aware of, thanks everyone for replies

Comment: mmmh... what if they save the input page locally on their hard disk and edit it so as to change the values of the drop down? :)

Comment: In that case we can save any input page locally sir and make changes to it, but when they will interact, they can only interact to server using page they are on unless there is something they can do to change the page by hacking..

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using, `Convert.ToInt32` on the value sent by the user, SQL injection would not occur. Invalid values would throw exceptions.

However it is a generally a good practice to use Parametrized queries.
That way even string values would be safe.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT dddd FROM table1 WHERE abcID NOT IN(@myID)");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@myID", abcID);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use parametrized queries as follows:

```
string sc = "SELECT dddd FROM table1 WHERE abcID NOT IN(@par)";

cmd=new SqlCommand(sc,conn);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@par",abcID );
da=newsqldataadapter(cmd);
ds=new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
cmd.excutenonquery();
```

**Go through Following:**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

No, this particular example cannot be used for SQL injection.

**However**, if you train yourself to **always** use stored procedures or parametrized queries, you will never get it into your system to create SQL statements like this. This way, you will never make something (possible by accident) that would create SQL injection attack vectors.

Comment: There's no need to use stored procedures for this. Parameterized queries can avoid SQL injection attacks perfectly well.

Comment: There are two examples of SQL injection in the comments under the question.  Would you like to revisit this answer?

Comment: @Ladadadada this case can never be a problem, because the resulting SQL inserts an integer, which can never hold any piece of SQL statement.

Answer (score 1):

For best practice you should use parameterized queries instead.

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT dddd FROM table1 WHERE abcID NOT IN( @Value )"
 command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Value", abcId));
```

You could *assume* that you are safe due to the fact that `Convert.ToInt32` will throw a `FormatException` if someone was to attempt to inject something like `DROP TABLE table1;` into your drop down list and pass it back to the server.  However, I would strongly recommend the use of paramertized queries.

Answer (score 1):

Since you converted the value to a 32bit integer, you won't be having "injection" problems. There are better ways to escape values though. (see parameterization)

Answer (score 1):

Not a nice way to do things, but it would survive sql injection... so, no... u won't have that problem